# Webstats for large Amazon S3/Cloudfront logs?

Tags: logging, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, awstats, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to find a way to parse our Amazon S3 access logs to get some webstats.

I've been trying to use AWStats 7, but I got to the point of where after day 9 of a given month it can't process any more logs because it runs out of memory. This server has 4gigs of memory

Our S3 logs are rather big(~1gig/day) and soon CloudFront logs could be 10-20gigs/day.

Is there any software that can generate webstats from S3(and soon cloudfront) logs?

I know about s3stat.com but I want something I can run on my own.

Comment: I process them using Webalizer with a little Python script to moosh the data around a bit so it works properly. Run each log through webalizer individually to update the database rather than combining the logs into one big file and trying to process that.

Comment: Do you have code that converts s3 logs into format that webalizer  can understand? or preferably patch for webalizer to understand s3/cloudfront logs?
for now my logs are split by day.

Comment: Not offhand, I'll see if I can grab it when I get home tonight and stick it on gist

Comment: Hey @Sam did you have a chance to find that script?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest [**GoAccess**](http://goaccess.prosoftcorp.com/). We are parsing about 120 million hits in about ~35mins, which is way faster than awstats. Seems like it doesn't consume a lot ram. (< 1GB) It's running on a 8GB RAM system.

You should give it a try though.

Comment: Note: I'm not familiar with Amazon S3 access logs. So feel free to delete this answer if it doesn't apply to it.

Comment: GoAccess looks very interesting and I'll be trying it on our servers. Thank you for sharing. However, I don't think it's a good match for this task. GoAccess is designed more for a snapshot-like realtime/near-realtime information. We don't need this kind of immediacy. A day old stats are sufficient. Even a week old is good too since we need it more for historical/analytical information. Also it looks like GoAccess can't natively parse S3 logs or save parsed reports. Each time going through 30gigs+/month of logs will be slow. Also we'd have to keep all the longs, I really don't want that.

Comment: This actually looks pretty interesting for Amazon S3 or Cloudfront: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/s3stat

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider running karmasphere analyst on EMR to run SQL queries against your CloudFront log directory (KSA knows how to query from bucket->folder->gzip->.log)

http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/karmasphere/

Comment: Is there some ready to use templates/presets for karmasphere for web stats? I think it'd take me forever to think of and write all the standard things I'd expect to see from webstats package.(plus as of right now I never worked with EMR)